# Bootstrap - Footer with two divs, want them to stack

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried Googling for this issue, but I have not found any examples that relate to my problem. My problem is as follows: I have a footer (with padding). Within this footer, I have a text on the far left side and text on the far right side.

**What I have:** When I scale the window down, eventually the text will lap over each other and a white space gets created underneath the footer - which the text falls out of.

**What I want:** At a certain point, both divs 'stack' underneath each other so that the text remains readable on smaller formats and that no extra white space gets created.

This is my website (which I uploaded real quick on BitBalloon): **removed link**

HTML code of footer:

```
<footer>
            <div class="row footer">
                <div class="aboutMe col-xs-6" p>
                    <span class="footerName">Temp Name</span>
                    <br><br>
                    <span class="footerDev">
                        Full Stack Web Developer
                        <br><br>
                        Responsive Designs
                    </span>
                </div>


                <div class="contactMe col-xs-6">
                    <span class="footerName">Contact</span>
                    <br><br>
                    <span class="footerDev">
                        <span><i class="icon ion-email"></i><a href="mailto:example@gmail.com?Subject=Question%20regarding%20your%20website" target="_top"> example@gmail.com</a></span><br>
                        <span><i class="icon ion-android-call"></i><a href="#"> (+31) 1 2345 1234</a></span><br>
                        <span><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i><a href="#" target="_blank"> LinkedIn</a></span><br>
                        <span><i class="icon ion-social-github"></i><a href="#" target="_blank">Github</a></span><br>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

CSS code of footer:

```
.row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footer {
    height: 250px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #1A4862;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.aboutMe {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.contactMe {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.footerName {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.footerDev {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.footer a {
    color: #fff
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `col-xs-6` to `col-sm-6` on both divs. Then when it reaches xs size they should stack.

Comment: @DustinPianalto They do indeed stack! However, the second div disappears in to white 'space' underneath the footer, that gets created.

Comment: That is because the height of your footer is fixed at 250px, try changing to `min-height: 250px`

Comment: @DustinPianalto Thank you very much. That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Just change your classes to allow only for `medium` screen devices:

```
<footer>
    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="aboutMe col-md-6" p>
            <span class="footerName">Temp Name</span>
            <br><br>
            <span class="footerDev">
                Full Stack Web Developer
                <br><br>
                Responsive Designs
            </span>
        </div>


        <div class="contactMe col-md-6">
            <span class="footerName">Contact</span>
            <br><br>
            <span class="footerDev">
                <span><i class="icon ion-email"></i><a href="mailto:example@gmail.com?Subject=Question%20regarding%20your%20website" target="_top"> example@gmail.com</a></span><br>
                <span><i class="icon ion-android-call"></i><a href="#"> (+31) 1 2345 1234</a></span><br>
                <span><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i><a href="#" target="_blank"> LinkedIn</a></span><br>
                <span><i class="icon ion-social-github"></i><a href="#" target="_blank">Github</a></span><br>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And in the CSS, kindly remove the `height` of the footer:

```
height: 250px;
```

Or may be if you are in a situation to set the `height`, consider setting it using `min-height`:

```
min-height: 250px;
```

Comment: Thank you! That removing of the height fixed it. Could you perhaps explain me why I shouldn't set a height for the footer? And why does, now when I remove the height, the height change according to the content? I don't understand.

Comment: @Cake You should never fix `height` because it should be naturally gauged by the content.

Comment: so I should make sure the height adjusts based on the content's padding/margin?

Comment: @Cake Kinda yes, but you should **not** set the height for anything using CSS. Setting `height` for contents is almost a crime.

Comment: @Cake If you need to set something, that might break, you can also set the `min-height` instead of `height`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much. Have a nice Christmas.

Comment: The only time I set a height is in the case where I need a set minimum height for layout purposes then I use min-height.